# What is the time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

problem size = 1 million

algorithm running time = N^2

operation per second = 10^9

The table in my algorithms book says it takes "hours" to complete, however I thought based off the information that it would take "minutes". My thought process was...

( 1 million )^2 / ( 10^9 ) = 1000 seconds which is less than an hour. Where did I go wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The table that you mentioned is most likely just giving a rough estimate, in the granularity of seconds/hours/days/years. The purpose of such a table might just be to convey a feeling about what O(N^2) actually means: Sorting a telephone book with 10000000 entries with an O(N^2) algorithm? Not a good idea.

This is affirmed by the fact that the asymptotic running time, when it is given in O-notation, omits any constant factor. So an algorithm in O(N^2) might actually perform, for example, **7.2** * N^2 operations to complete its task. And there you have 7200 seconds - that is, 2 *hours*.